# How to disable Open publish dashboard button from modal popup?

Tags: publishing, publishing-service

We have installed Sitecore Publishing Service to separate Sitecore publishing. We got a request from client to allow only admins to Open publish dashboard button and for non-admins, this button should be disabled. For this, we have written a custom JS to hide the button but that is not loading.

[image]

I would like to disable the Language and Target checkbox selections from publishing popup.

[image]

Please help us here.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you want to disable a button that is a part of `Speak UI`. For this, you need to check the location of the files that get installed with the Publishing service. So if you extract the `Sitecore Publishing package`, you will find the location of the files that will be installed in your Sitecore instance. The location of these files will be this.

```
wwwroot\your-sitecore-instance\sitecore\shell\client\Applications\Publishing
```

You have to write some JS code to disable or hide the button, I got the reference from the Sitecore basic publishing service panel, that I found under this location.

```
wwwroot\your-sitecore-instance\sitecore\shell\Applications\Dialogs\Publish
```

Under the file `pubilsh.js`, you will find an example of writing the JS code. Now for the polishing service, under `sitecore\shell\client\Applications\Publishing` folder, there is a file called `PublishingDialog.js`. Here I tried to write a custom code to hide the publish button like this at the end of the file.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    
    var publishButton = $('.sc-dialogFooter-content-buttons').find("[data-sc-id='ButtonPublish']")
    
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(publishButton).hide();
    }, 1000);

});
```

And it hides the button. This answers your question that how to write JS. Next you need to do this for a particular role. Not sure but you need to call some API that may give you the identity of the logged-in user and you can write the condition on the basis of the role.

Lastly, I would say that you can try this as well if you want to use custom JS with the `Speak UI` then you can put it anywhere in your Sitecore solution, and using the `Sitecore Rocks`, go to the presentation details of your page item and double-click on the `PageCode` component to open its Properties. There is a `PageCodeScriptFileName` to the path of your .js file.

Follow this article for more references.

https://mhwelander.net/2014/07/01/speak-for-newbies-part-4-pagecode-and-javascript-libraries/